# Android studio configuration with Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, configuration, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having an issue to configure Android studio after importing gradle project. My project structures is as following:

```
Root Project
|_.config
    |_settings.gradle
    |_build.gradle
|_app_module
|_lib1_module
|_lib2_module
|_ etc.
```

Please note, that for several reasons I am **not able** to move *settings.gradle* and *build.gradle* files to project root . Also, the files mentioned above are configured correctly, so there is no problem with the build.

So the problem is that once the project in imported, the all gradle related file and folders are are generated inside *.config* folder, which doesn't disturd me. 
Also the *.idea* folder and all relevant sub-folders are generated in this very folder.

So this is the problem. For some reason, the studio doesn't recognize all sub-modules are under source control. I.e. it's *vcs.xml* is empty and contains only project root. Actually the problem is resolved by adding the modules via **settings--> subversion** menu, but I'd really like out-of-the-box solution. I've tried to put *.idea* folder under source-control - doesn't help. Upon project creation, the *vcs.xml* is re-written and empty again.

So, the main question is:
Is there a possibility to

1. Force studio to generate .idea folder and the root project folder without changing location of .gradle files **OR**
2. Make studio **NOT** to re-write it's settings files upon project import (e.g. keep predefined vcs.xml)

PS. I'm aware the putting all generated files (including gradle folder, gradlew, etc.) will probably solve the issue, but I wouldn't like to go so far.

Thank all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a comment, but it is too long.

Android Studio works with a project.
Inside this project you can configure more modules but it need this structure:

```
Root Project
|_.idea
|_.gradle
|_.config
    |_build.gradle
|_app_module
    |_build.gradle
|_lib1_module
    |_build.gradle
|_lib2_module
    |_build.gradle
|_ etc.
|_settings.gradle
|_build.gradle
```

Inside the settings.gradle you have to define all modules:

```
include ':config' , ':app_module' , ':lib1_module',  ':lib2_module'
```

Under the root folder, Android Studio when builds the project with gradle, makes same folders, like the `.idea`.

I read that your are not able to move the `settings.gradle` file.
In this case Android Studio recognizes the config folder as the root of a project and build the .idea folder inside.

```
|_.config (root)
    |_.idea
    |_.gradle
    |_build.gradle
    |_settings.gradle
    |_myModule
```

> Force studio to generate .idea folder and the root project folder without changing location of .gradle files OR

As I know you can't avoid this.

Also ,

> Make studio NOT to re-write it's settings files upon project import

The `.idea`, the `.gradle` folder, the .iml files are built locally by the IDE when the project is built. The IDE re-writes these resources, also these files contain local paths and usually they are not commited in VCS for this reason.